# This is a codevita problem which is giving me wrong answer on submission . anyone can check what i did wrong in my approach

Tags: java

Question is as follows
A Board Game
Problem Description
You are given an N x N grid of squares. Each square except the top left is filled with a positive integer. You start at the top left corner with a score of 0 and move to the bottom right square by moving either right by one square or down by one square. As you move to the new square, your score becomes [S/2] + k, where S was the score at your previous square and k is the number written in the current square. In the above, [x] is the largest integer which is not greater than x. Thus, [5] is 5, and [5.5] is also 5.

Write a program to find the smallest score with which you can exit the grid.

Constraints
4 <= N <= 30

Number in each square <= 1000

Input Format
The first line contains a single integer N, representing the size of the grid

The next N lines, each having N space separated integers giving the numbers written on successive rows of the grid

Output
The smallest score with which you can exit the grid

Time Limit
1

Explanation
Example 1

Input

Input

4

0 3 9 6

1 4 4 5

8 2 5 4

1 8 5 9

Output

12

Explanation

N=4. The set of scores are as given. The 4 X 4 scores look as follows

One possible set of moves are down, right, down, right, right, down.

The corresponding scores are 1, 4, 4, 7, 7, 12

Example 2

Input

5

0 82 2 6 7

4 3 1 5 21

6 4 20 2 8

6 6 64 1 8

1 65 1 6 4

Output

7

Explanation

One possible set of moves are down, right, right, right, down, down, down, right

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class A_Board_Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[][] board = new int[n][n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                board[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minscore(board,n));
    }
    public static int minscore(int[][] a, int n){
        int ans = 0,i=0,j=0;
        while(i+1<n && j+1<n){
           if(a[i+1][j]<a[i][j+1]){
               ans = (ans/2) + a[i+1][j];
               i = i+1;
           //    System.out.println("down is "+ans);
           }
           else{
               ans = (ans/2) + a[i][j+1];
               j=j+1;
             //   System.out.println("right is "+ans);
           }
        }     
        ans = (ans/2) + a[n-1][n-1];  
        return ans;
    }  
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

// Bro i don't know the problem with your code but here this is my solution
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DP_codevita {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int a=sc.nextInt();


int arr[][]=new int[a][a];

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
{ for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
    {  
    arr[i][j]=sc.nextInt();

    }   
}
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{ for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
    {  if(i==0 && j==0)
       {
        arr[i][j]=0;
       }
        else if(i==0 && j!=0)
       {   
          arr[i][j]= (int)Math.floor((arr[i][j-1]/2)+arr[i][j]);
       }
       else if(i!=0 && j==0)
       {
            arr[i][j]= (int)Math.floor((arr[i-1][j]/2)+arr[i][j]);
       }
       else
       { 
           int min=Math.min(arr[i][j-1], arr[i-1][j]);
            arr[i][j]= (int)Math.floor((min/2)+arr[i][j]);
       }


    }   
}

     System.out.println(arr[a-1][a-1]);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

In your code You just check for a if right or bottom value is lesser then move to that side, the problem is here. Maybe next element is smaller than the element that you have left before.